# Progressbar not Progressing in c#

Tags: c#

The Code is given below. it receives filepaths in a list from Form1 and then whole transformation takes place here and everything is working fine BUT the PROBLEM is that progressbar1 does not progress.. what could be the reason? Thanks in advance!

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        numericUpDown1.Enabled = false;
        numericUpDown2.Enabled = false;
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    List<string> filepath_ = new List<string>();
    int count = 0, total = 0;
    private string format = string.Empty;
    private int _height = 0;
    private int _width = 0;

    internal void passpath(List<string> fp)
    {
        filepath_.AddRange(fp);
        total = filepath_.Count;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text == "Stop")
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            button1.Text = "Transform";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Text = "Stop";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        foreach (string filepath in filepath_)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
            ImageFormat imageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            switch (format)
            {
                case "JPEG":
                    imageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    break;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            string finalpath = filepath.Substring(0, filepath.IndexOf('.'));
            Image image1 = Image.FromFile(filepath);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(filepath);

            if (_height != 0 && _width != 0 && format!=string.Empty)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image1, _width, _height);
                bitmap.Save(finalpath + " (" + _width.ToString() + "x" + _height.ToString() + ")." +format, imageFormat);
            }
            else if (_height != 0 && _width != 0)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image1, _width, _height);
                bitmap.Save(finalpath + " (" + _width.ToString() + "x" + _height.ToString() + ")" + ext);
            }
            else if (format != string.Empty)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image1);
                bitmap.Save(finalpath+"." + format, imageFormat);
            }
            count++;

            int i = ((count / total) * 100);

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

        label6.Text = count.ToString() + " Out of " + total.ToString() + " Images transformed";


    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "Transform";
        progressBar1.Value = 0;

        if (e.Cancelled)
            MessageBox.Show("Transformation stopped. " + count.ToString() + " images transformed.");
        else if (e.Error != null)
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(count.ToString() + " Images Transformed");
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        format = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _width = 640;
        _height = 480;
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should've deleted all parts of source that are not relevant to the problem!

Comment: I m really sorry for that actually this z my first time i posted a question n didnt knw abt it... next tym i ll  careful

Answer (score 1):

Change you variables to doubles:

```
double count = 0, total = 0;
```

When you do this calculation:

```
int i = ((count / total) * 100);
```

You're currently doing integer arithmetic. The result of `count / total` (i.e `1 / 10` or `4 / 10`) is rounded to `0`. When you divide that by `100`, the result is still `0`, so your `ProgressBar` won't move.

Using the `double` type will correctly store the fractional part of your quotient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. 1 thing more what can i do that progressbar reaches the end and stays there after done transforming all the images?

Answer (score 1):

The problem had already been pointed out by Grant Winney: It's the integer division.

Without changing data types of `count` and/or `total` you could use this:

`int i = (int)((100.0 * count) / total)`

or that:

`int i = (100 * count) / total`

where the former makes `100.0 * count` a double and the division by `total` as well. The latter sticks to integer operations by simply multiplying `count` first (changing sequence of operations), such that the division will not be 0 as long as `count` is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
pBar.Step = 2;
pBar.PerformStep();
```